How can I correctly set the work_email field to be read-only only for the Sales Executive group?
I have a custom new module in odoo 17   , I want to set  'work_email' field set as read only for employees, the work_email field is already have in hr module (res_users.py) and  it the employee user profile it have a many field so i want to customize
so i tried create a new group in sales employee category the name is sales executive .
in hr group it alreadery have two groups are admin and officer. these are have full access in the profile . if the normal employees go to the profile , they are only have read mode option if they are not have any group selected in the hr category.
so i want to try set full access by using officer group from hr and i add additionally sales executive group in the employee users , and i now i want to declare if the user has sales executive group , the work email only want to go read only so How to achieve this task?
Profile page
group in groups page
my codes:
module : custom_sales_module
models:custom_res_users.py:
[```class CustomUserProfile(models.Model):
_inherit = 'res.users'


security/ir_model_group :


[```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <record model="ir.module.category" id="module_category_custom_sales">
            <field name="name">Sales Role</field>
            <field name="sequence">10</field>
        </record>
        <record id="custom_sales_security_executive_group" model="res.groups">
            <field name="name">Sales Executive</field>          
            <field name="category_id" ref="custom_sales_group.module_category_custom_sales" />
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>```]

views:
custom_res_users_views:

[```
<odoo>
    <data>
        <record id="custom_user_profile_security_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">custom.user.profile.security.view</field>
            <field name="model">res.users</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.res_users_view_form_profile" />
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                 <!-- <page name="personal_information" position="attributes">
                    <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
                </page> -->
                <xpath expr="//field[@name='work_email']" position="attributes">
                    <t groups="custom_sales_group.custom_sales_security_executive_group">
                        <attribute name="readonly">1</attribute>
                    </t>
                </xpath>
          </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```]




but by this code ,this field not set readonly for sales executive group it set globally.


so check my code and give correct code:



